# Rephrasing "The voice in his head that normally took him apart was cutting him some slack. Every now and then, it actually gave him some credit"

Tags: sentence-meaning

> The voice in his head that normally took him apart was cutting him some slack. Every now and then, it actually gave him some credit.
> — David Corbett

I'd like to rephrase the above sentence to make the meaning more clear because the meaning of the sentence comes to me in a vague way.

Any good rephrasings would be very appreciated.

Comment: The voice in his head that normally severely criticised him was making allowances for him. Every now and then, it praised him.

Comment: @BEBYGONES, you can see your question is being downvoted out the wazoo (i.e. a lot). I'm not one of the downvoters, but here's my suggestion as to the problem. It's probably that your phrase "in a vague way" is itself too vague. As a result, it's not very clear as to what aspects of the original text are confusing. It might be that you are unsure as to the meanings of phrases like, "took him apart", and "cutting him some slack". But maybe it's something else. In general, questions arising from confusion about meaning are best if they explain exactly what is confusing and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The voice in his head that normally **took him apart** was **cutting him some slack**. Every now and then, it actually gave him some credit.

I add to what @Michael Harvey has said.

to **take somebody apart** means

> to defeat someone very easily in a sport: He took their defence apart, scoring three goals in the first 20 minutes.
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-sb-apart)

In OP's example, it means the person would normally feel defeated easily [and heavily] by that voice.

to **cut somebody some slack** means

> to not judge someone as severely as you usually would because they are having problems at the present time: "Andrew's late again." "Cut him some slack - his wife just had a baby."
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cut-sb-some-slack)

We could consider

> The voice in his head/His imagination that normally **made him feel heavily defeated** was **giving him some reprieve**.  Every now and then, it actually gave him some credit.

Answer (score 0):

The voice in his head normally criticized him. However, now it was not doing that. In fact, every now and then, it even gave him some credit.

Comment: Are you copy from [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/316771/the-voice-in-his-head-that-normally-took-him-apart-was-cutting-him-some-slack-e#comment594451_316771) comment?

Comment: @Eden0516 - I felt that the question was so weak that I did not want to create an actual answer, however a spirit of helpfulness, possibly misguided, led me to summarise the sentence.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, but I'm asking if he is copying from you or not.

Comment: @Eden0516 - yes, I know. It's not an exact copy.

Comment: @Eden0516, no I didn't copy from Michael. In fact his answer wasn't even there when I wrote mine (check the time stamps). However, his is better than mine so I'm glad it got the acceptance check.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, I applaud your spirit of helpfulness  (In light of the ell.meta question I just [posted](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5690/are-we-getting-grumpier-a-call-for-a-gentler-touch)).

Comment: @Eden0516, wait -- you meant Michael's comment, not the accepted answer (which wasn't Michael's). His comment did indeed precede my answer, but no of course I didn't copy it, any more than Michael "copied" the original sentence!  His perfectly fine answer focused on exchanging colloquial phrases with more standard phrasing. My intent was to simplify the more compound structural aspects.

Comment: @tkp So you don't need to mention that in your answer?

Comment: @tkp [Are you promoting your post?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/316771/rephrasing-the-voice-in-his-head-that-normally-took-him-apart-was-cutting-him-s/316779?noredirect=1#comment594478_316779)

Comment: @Eden0516 In my view, this isn't plagiarism. Even if tkp had read Michael's comment and reworded it --and I'm happy to accept tkp's word that this is not the case, but if that had happened, it would be fine, since plagiarism is the copying of original text, not the re-expression of ideas. Half of everything I've contributed to this site came from my own expression of other people's ideas.

Comment: @gotube In my opinion, that is not plagiarism. Even if tkp had already read Michael's comment and rephrased it--and I am glad to accept tkps'word that this isn't the case, but if that had happened, it is fine, as plagiarism is the copying of the original text instead of the re-expression of ideas. About have of everything I have contributed to ELL came from my own expression of other's ideas.  So this isn't plagiarism?